# Работа с ReentrantLock

Tags: java

Насколько я понимаю, класс ReentrantLock - это альтернатива synchronized. И его задачи синхронизировать потоки, если они работают с общим обьектом.

Если что не так, поправляйте.

```
public class TestMultithreading{
    static int count = 0; // совместный примитив на 2 потока
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Client());
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Client());
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}

public class Client implements Runnable{
    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (TestMultithreading.count <= 10) {
            lock.lock();
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + TestMultithreading.count);
            TestMultithreading.count++;
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
```

Правильно:

```
Thread-0 0
Thread-0 1
Thread-0 2
Thread-0 3
Thread-0 4
Thread-0 5
Thread-0 6
Thread-0 7
Thread-0 8
Thread-0 9
Thread-0 10
Thread-1 0
```

Неправильно:

```
Thread-0 0
Thread-0 1
Thread-0 2
Thread-1 0
Thread-1 4
Thread-1 5
Thread-0 3
Thread-1 7
Thread-1 8
Thread-1 9
Thread-1 10
Thread-0 8
```

Результат выходит правильный раз через раз. Почему так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, в вашем случе каждый поток синхронизируется по своей блокировке, что никак не исключает одновременного доступа потоков к разделяемой переменной. Т.е. блокировка должна быть общей для обшей переменной.

Во-вторых, оба приведенных вами примера вывода являются не тем, что вы ожидаете, т.к. поток получает блокировку на каждую итерацию цикла, а не на весь цикл. Т.е. даже если вы перепишете код с использованием общей блокировки, вы все равно будете получать разные результаты.

Comment: Как можно реализовать пункт 1?

Comment: @romashechka Так я же все сказал, вам нужен один общий экземпляр `ReentrantLock`, а не два.

Comment: на счет пункта 2, с общим ReentrantLock все работает отлично и стабильно

Comment: @romashechka тем не менее, это не значит, что ваш код корректен и делает действительно то, что вам нужно.

Comment: Скажите еще такую вещь. Я изучаю по книге Хорстмана. Он пишет, что до java 5 использовалось для данных случаев ключевое слово synchronized, но с java 5 надо использовать ReentrantLock вместо synchronized. Можно с этим безоговорочно согласиться или это зависит от случаев???

Comment: Здесь хороший ответ http://www.javaspecialist.ru/2011/11/synchronized-vs-reentrantlock.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Client implements Runnable{
private static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
@Override
public void run() {
    while (TestMultithreading.count <= 10) {
        lock.lock();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + TestMultithreading.count);
        TestMultithreading.count++;
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```